# Accessing file in Docker image within Kubernetes pod?

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I am building a custom image and baking a file underneath a pre-defined path. When trying to access a file within this path once I deploy my pod on the K8s cluster, the file cannot be found.

When I run the image locally, I can exec into the container and see the file. When I exec into the pod, I cannot see the file. Do I need to specify a volume/volume mount to access it? How can I do this correctly? I tried adding a volume and volumeMount against the same path, but it's just an empty directory

Comment: If the file is baked into the image, the pod should have it. If it is not present, you are probably overwriting it with a volume mount which apparently is empty.

Comment: Thanks. I was just verifying since I'm having issues copying a file. Must be a different issue. Thanks.

Comment: @John if possible, please include your Dockerfiles and K8s manifests. It will make finding a solution easier.